# Regex remove comma and space at the last character only

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a newbie with regex.. I've tried to remove comma and space `,`  at the last character like this.

this is my string

```
var str = "Gang Cipicung 7, Kebon Gedang, Kecamatan Batununggal, "
```

this is my regex

```
str.replace(/[, ]+/g, " ").trim()
```

this is my expect

```
Gang Cipicung 7, Kebon Gedang, Kecamatan Batununggal
```

how can I deal with it, Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, @RameshRajendran Thanks.. it works in an elegant way. Thanks for reference man you made may day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` charactor means the end of string. this will work

```
str.replace(/[, ]+$/, "")
```

Comment: Hi @Junho Ahn Its work,, Thanks man

Comment: I'm glad it the code could help you. in extra, ^ character means the start of string.